# Primefaces Schedule adding data to event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I can't seem to get data into an event

public LeadListScheduleController() throws ParseException {
            eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();

```
for (int i = 0; i < leadList.size(); i++)
{
    if((leadList.get(i).next_action != null && !leadList.get(i).next_action.isEmpty())&&(leadList.get(i).next_action_date != null && !leadList.get(i).next_action_date.isEmpty()))
    eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent(""+leadList.get(i).next_action+" "+leadList.get(i).business_name + " - " +leadList.get(i).id, nextLeadActionDate(leadList.get(i).next_action_date), nextLeadActionDate(leadList.get(i).next_action_date)));  
}
```

What I want to do is add the variable leadList.get(i).id to the call as the data object, if I add it to the end of this constructor it goes in as a Style Class.

Anyone see a easy way to get it in there?

Comment: data has to be an object, and then you can get it when event selected by (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject()

Answer (score 0):

Data needs to be an object. It has to be declared as an object before passing in.